# Duffing oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to draw the phase space of this modification of Duffing oscillator:
\begin{align}
 \dot x &= y,\\
 \dot y &= x - x^3  - ay  - (x^2)y \quad \text{ when } \quad a=1 \; \text{ and }  \;a=5.
\end{align}

I know that critical points are $(0, 0)$, $(-1, 0)$, and $(1, 0),$ and I have demonstrated that when $a =1$ I have a spiral the form $(\pm1,0)$ and when $a = 5$ not.

Does someone know how to draw it?

Thank you.

Comment: Improve your question, pls.

Comment: Why did you revert back the edit made by Key Flex?

Comment: Do you mean draw with a computer program or do a sketch by hand if no computer is available?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

[image]

generated with python:

```
import numpy as  np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xmin, xmax = -2.0, 2.0
ymin, ymax = -1.0, 1.0

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 30, endpoint = True), np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 30, endpoint = True))

a = 1
u = y
v = x - x**3 - a * y - x**2 * y


plt.streamplot(x, y, u, v)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer has been very helpful.